# The 'from' method of Observable in Angular2 context

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code inside the constructor of my Angular2 component class:

```
Observable.from([1,2,3]).subscribe(e=>{
         console.log(e);
       });
```

I imported the following:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
```

When I load the page in my browser, I expected 1, 2, 3 in my console output, but it is not happening. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working, check the place where you subscribe,

```
export class App {
  constructor() {
   Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).subscribe(e=>{
         console.log(e);
       });
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/3ExoDAtapuJ7BOo1b0aq?p=preview)**

Comment: May be working on Plunger with different set of resources imported, but not working for me with the resources that I have imported. What I have to import more?

Comment: check the plunker and compare

Comment: How to compare a CDN resource and an npm installed resource?!

Comment: imports you have and can you post the full component code

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
Observable.of(1,2,3).subscribe(e=>{
         console.log(e);
       });
```